# Parent method not working in IE using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class using jquery and it's working fine in chrome on clicking li element. But the same is not working in IE

Here is my code

```
 jQuery(document).on('click','.flexible', function(e) {
     $(this).parent().addClass('open');
 });
```

This works abnormally

Comment: which IE? create a codepen at least...

Comment: IE 11 is the version